# How to disable SSL v3 for sun os 5.6 (OAS 4.0.8), I am facing POODLE vulnerability issue?

Tags: poodle-attack, sslv3, oas

My Website is hosted on `Sun OS 5.06 (OAS 4.0.8)` and using web server : `Oracle_Web_Listener/4.0.8.` Website is configured to use https for secure pages and it was working fine from last 10 years but suddenly i am getting complaints from my customers that they can not browse site on `chrome version 40` and above and `firefox 34` and above.

I searched for this issue and found that there is `POODLE attack` which may causing this issue. now the only solution i can see is to disable `SSL v3` on server.

Can any help me out with the process or an idea, How to disable SSL V3 on this `Olde server`? Its `sun microsystem server`.